# MongoDB returns wrong results for count query

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, mongodb-ruby

```
> filters = {search_created_at: {$lte: ISODate("2016-04-28T23:25:31.818Z")}}
{ "search_created_at" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2016-04-28T23:25:31.818Z") } }
> db.collection_name.find(filters).count()
18371526
> 
> db.collection_name.find().count()
18371316
>
```

Total count for a collection comes out to be less than filtered count. Weird. If anyone could help???
TIA

Comment: Can you give your db structure as well?

Comment: there is just one collection in the db used for analytics purpose. This collection has denormalized data.

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Probably not !!

Answer (score 1):

this could be corrupted index issue, try rebuild indexes and run your query again

```
db.collection.reIndex()
```

[more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/)